# RecyclerView does not preserve scroll position when data changed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of articles and when new articles appear on the server, I display the button informing user about that. When user clicks this button I want to load newest articles and add them to beginning of the list. While new articles are loading, I am displaying placeholder items (view skeletons of article item without data) for them in the RecyclerView and I scroll to top of the list so newest articles are visible.

The problem is that when new articles are fetched and they replace placeholders, the RecyclerView is not scrolled to the top but instead is scrolled on previous data and I have to manually scroll to be at the top of the list.

This has probably something to do with attempt of RecyclerView to keep user scrolled where he was before, but in this case, user was not here.

The workaround around this is either disable animations on RecyclerView or to not make diff of the data using `DiffUtil` but call `notifyDatasetChanged`.

I went with the second approach because I want to have animations

I have created a showcase [repository](https://github.com/davidbilik/recyclerview-scroll-bug) demonstrating this problem. There are two Activities, one with vanilla `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` and second one using [epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) library.

The code for the whole class is pretty complicated and I am not sure which is more relevant so this is how the whole [`Activity`](https://github.com/davidbilik/recyclerview-scroll-bug/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ackee/scrollingsample/MainActivityRVAdapter.kt) looks. She simulation of loading new articles

```
private fun simulateFetchNewArticles() {
        scope.launch {
            val newArticlesCount = 10
            adapter.items = (0 until newArticlesCount).map { Item.Placeholder("Placeholder $it") } + adapter.items
            delay(100)
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
            delay(5000)
            // Uncomment for workaround fix
            // adapter.items = emptyList()
            adapter.items = (0 until newArticlesCount).map { Item.Article("New article $it") } + adapter.items.drop(newArticlesCount)
        }
    }
```